# AHK missing "}"

Tags: syntax-error, autohotkey

I have these 5 lines of code:

```
^+E:: { SendInput {è} } return
^+A:: { SendInput {á} } return
^+N:: { SendInput {ñ} } return
^+G:: { SendInput {ŋ} } return
^+S:: { SendInput {š} } return
```

When I run the code, it says there is a missing "}" on line 5. I've added 20 extra "}"s on line 5 but still gives the same error.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHK error messages are horrible sometimes. Try

```
^+E::SendInput è
^+A::SendInput á
^+N::SendInput ñ
^+G::SendInput ŋ
^+S::SendInput š
```

You don't need `return` for single-line hotkeys. Also, `Send` would work just as well.